# Is it generally considered OK to store a query string in a database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, query-string

If I were to take a query string from an incoming request HTTP request in a web application, store it directly in a MySql database, then use it later to re-build the original request url, would that be considered OK?

I'm wondering if there are any "gotchas" like special characters or multi-byte characters on the query string that might require me to encode the data or something before storing it.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: My particular use case would be something like the following. Although my main concern is more about whether or not any special characters on a query string could cause unexpected problems.

- User submits a form.
- During form processing, we determine that user needs to confirm their email
- We send the user an email for confirmation and store the original query string in database because we always want to carry through any query string parameters that were on the request.
- After the user confirms their email, we redirect them back to the original form url, and append the original query string to ensure query string parameters are carried through.

Comment: you should elaborate on your use case and provide an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything inherently wrong with it, but it makes more sense to me to store the parsed out values instead of the data in querystring format. It might future-proof it a little more, for example if you changed the name of the query string parameters in your app at a later time.

**Elaborating:**
Instead of storing "?param1=A&param2=B&param3=C" into a field called "querystring"
it would probably be better to store A, B, and C into three fields called "Param1, Param2, and Param3.

**Update:**
Based on the use case you added to your question, specifically the part about this data only needing to be stored temporarily until the user has confirmed their account, I don't think there is anything wrong with storing the query string in raw format. If you were intending long term storage of this info my original recommendation stands.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I don't understand what you mean with "store the parsed out values instead of the data in querystring format".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! My thought was that just storing the string itself was sort of "future-proof"-ing in the sense that if additional query string values are added to the url in the future, I would not have to add additional fields to support the new parameters.

Comment: @Jason: It depends on what the parameters mean. Do you plan on extracting their values directly from the database, or do you plan on using the string solely for URL reconstruction?

Comment: @Jack Consider this query string: `name=John&age=30`. You'd then not store the string itself but the values `John` for property `name` and `30` for the property `age`.

Comment: I suppose it depends somewhat on exactly what the purpose of storing the parameters is in the context of your app. It could go either way, but I still think it is best not to store formatting information in the DB in this situation. You get the additional benefit of being able to easily query the parameters independently with this approach too. Plus, why use up the extra DB storage space for the parameter names which presumably don't change?

Comment: @Jack, I see what you mean. In this particular use case, depending on where the request is coming from, it is possible that a value will be appended to the url simply for carry-through. These cases are usually associated with some sort of tracking code. We would rather not have to explicitly add a field for every query string parameter that could be added, because at some point someone would forget to do this and something would break. However, i think in other cases what you're suggesting would make perfect sense.

Comment: A better question is, why are you storing the URL in the first place? That might shed some light on the best approach.

Comment: My last comment was meant to say @John

Answer (score 1):

I would be sure to use bindings on the queries stored.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_OF_QUERIES (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (?,?,?);
```

Comment: OK, to prevent sql injection attacks I am guessing?

Comment: Yes :) And you won't have to worry about other quotes or special characters inside your stored query messing with the rest of your insert wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Why stop at the QueryString? If you want to save some of the header, why not save the entire header info including cookies, post data, etc..

Comment: Hmmm... very interesting thought. In the right situation that would work, I'm just considering whether or not that would help me or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. I worked in a financial institution where every transaction that occurred were stored in a database, including the SQL query. This was used for transaction audit, used for auditing and report generation. Also, it gives good history of a user's transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what for really.

If you're dealing with another server, and the query string is all you have to identify the request (well, the URI, but presumably you are banking on the rest being static, maybe check that assumption), then it's ideal to use what is essentially an identifier, as an identifier.

If your code is on the server processing the query itself, then it won't be ideal for many purposes, though can be for logging and some caching uses.

If your code deals with the actual parameters of the query, then probably not.